# npm install is reporting unreferenced versions of Angular components

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have an Angular application, which uses local shared component (via our own npm server - Verdaccio)

I updated one of the shared libraries, and uses `npm link` to share it into my application to test, and all went well.

I then built it and pushed it the our npm server.

Now, when I try to `npm install` (npm version 7.21.1) it, I get the following error

```
    $ npm i @my-comany/my-component-ui@7.0.5
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: @my-comany/my-application@0.0.1
    npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@12.0.5
    npm ERR!   2 more (@angular/animations, @angular/cdk)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"12.2.4" from @angular/common@12.2.4
    npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
    npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^12.0.5" from the root project
    npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.2.4
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
    npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^12.0.5" from the root project
    npm ERR!     1 more (@my-comany/my-suite-ui)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My application has the following Angular related dependencies..

```
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/common": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/core": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/forms": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/material": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/router": "^12.0.5",
    
    
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.5",
        "@angular/cli": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.5",
        "@angular/language-service": "^12.0.5",
```

And the shared lib I am trying to install has

```
        "peerDependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "~12.0.5",
            "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.5",
            "@angular/common": "~12.0.5",
            "@angular/core": "~12.0.5",         
            "@angular/forms": "~12.0.5",
            "@angular/material": "^12.0.5",
            "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.5",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.5",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.5",
```

I have looked through all my package files, and there is no mention of `@angular/core@"12.2.4" from @angular/common@12.2.4` anywhere.

Where might this could be coming from, or how can I diagnose it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a guess, but try to change

```json
"@angular/core": "^12.0.5",
```

to

```json
"@angular/core": "~12.0.5",
```

There's a chance that you'll have to do this with other packages too in order to make this work e.g. this here is what I have:

```json
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
```

From [this page](https://michaelsoolee.com/npm-package-tilde-caret/#:%7E:text=npm%20uses%20the%20tilde%20(%7E),means%20to%20install%20version%201.0.&text=you%20see%20%5E1.0.-,2%20it%20means%20to%20install%20version%201.0.,patch%20version%20such%20as%201.1.) about semantic versioning:

> ```
> major.minor.patch
>
> 1.0.2
> ```
>
> Major, minor and patch represent the different releases of a package.
>
> npm uses the tilde (`~`) and caret (`^`) to designate which patch and minor versions to use respectively.
>
> So if you see `~1.0.2` it means to install version `1.0.2` or the latest patch version such as `1.0.4`. If you see `^1.0.2` it means to install version `1.0.2` or the latest minor or patch version such as `1.1.0`.

Comment: I am not sure if it because I previously did a force, and I changed all the ng refs to use "~", but npm install no works with now errors (and without a force). Wow, never thought of the above (ie ^ vs ~) and did not realise I had them mixed (though most came from the last `ng update`. Anyway thankyou.